# How to send parameters in a StringRequest?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

```
class test2 : AppCompatActivity(){

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2)
    connect()

 }

 fun connect(){
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://www.example.com/Register.php"
    val params = HashMap<String,String>()
    params["abc"] = "parm1"
    params["def"] = "parm2"
    params["ghi"] = "parm3"

    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            text_test.text = "Response is: $response"
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { text_test.text = "That didn't work! " })
    queue.add(stringRequest)
  }
}
```

I want to send the parameters in `StringRequest` and not in `JsonObjectRequest`.

The parameters should be in `"param1=data1&param2=data2&param3=data3"` format

and UTF-8 encoded.

Any idea how i can send the data in that format ?